# keep linebreaks with Jsoup

Tags: java, apache-poi, jsoup

I have a .docx document which looks like this:

```
1. Part One
   Some <message>xml</message> text
2. Part Two
   Some plain text
```

I want to get the plain text content and remove all xml-tags.
Therefore I use Apache poi and Jsoup:

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(path));
XWPFWordExtractor wordxExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
String content = wordxExtractor.getText();
System.out.println(content);
content = Jsoup.parse(content).text();
System.out.println(content);
```

This prints:

```
Part One
Some <message>xml</message> text
Part Two
Some plain text
```

and:

```
Part One Some xml text Part Two Some plain text
```

The problem now is:
After xml-parsing, the line breaks don't appear anymore - how can I avoid this (I want to keep the line breaks) ?

Comment: Hm, I don't think so: in your suggested question, the line breaks got removed because of <br>-tags, but here I don't have such tags.

Comment: Oh wait, it's pretty similar: In the top answer, I just had to replace `.replaceAll("(?i)<br[^>]*>", "br2n")` with `.replaceAll("\n", "br2n")`